# How does the Cayley–Hamilton theorem give me a formula for eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

The wikipedia page [Eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3%C3%973_matrices) gives an example of how to compute eigenvectors of a matrix if already given the eigenvalues.  The page claims this is an application of the [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).   However, when I read the Cayley–Hamilton theorem page, I don't see how it applies?

Can someone help me understand which part of the Cayley–Hamilton theorem gives me the formula for eigenvectors, and in particular how to apply the theorem in the special cases of repeated eigenvalues or if there is a zero eigenvalue?

There is an example on the eigenvalues page of how to compute some eigenvectors of a $3\times 3$ matrix, given its eigenvalues, but I'm not 100% sure how this applies to larger $n\times n$ matrices.

Which part is unclear to me?
Apparently the kth eigenvector is the kth column of the matrix formed by multiplying $(A-\lambda_k)^{-1}\prod_{i =1}^{n}(A-\lambda_i I) = \prod_{i \ne k}(A-\lambda_i I)$
in the case that $\lambda_k$ is not a repeated eigenvalue.

How is this a consequence of the Cayley–Hamilton theorem, and how do I modify this formula to account for repeated eigenvalues and zero-eigenvalues?

Comment: Which part did you not understand? The page is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @Ricky I've updated the question to explain what is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity $m$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is then in the form of $(x-\lambda)^mg(x)$ for some polynomial $g$ such that $g(\lambda)\ne0$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have $(A-\lambda I)^mg(A)=0$.

We haven’t calculated any eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ yet, but its existence is theoretically guaranteed. Let $v$ be such an eigenvector. Note that
$$
g(A)v=g(\lambda)v\ne0.
$$
Therefore $g(A)$ must be a nonzero matrix. Let’s say its $j$-th column is nonzero, so that $x:=g(A)e_j\ne0$ (where $e_j$ denotes the $j$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb F^n$). Then
$$
(A-\lambda I)^mx
=(A-\lambda I)^mg(A)e_j
=0e_j=0.
$$
Therefore, there exists a least positive integer $k\le m$ such that
$$
(A-\lambda I)^{k}x=0.
$$
Now let $v:=(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}x$. Then $v\ne0$ and $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. Hence $v$ an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

In particular, if the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $m=1$, any nonzero column of $g(A)$ will be a corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  However, I still don't see where to read the eigenvectors from.  I can compute the matrix of $\prod (A - \lambda_k I)$ for all $k$ other than the index of the eigenvalue in question.  However, which column of the resulting matrix do I grab the eigenvector from?

Comment: Should I just take any non-zero column?

Comment: @JimNewton Yes, you may take any nonzero column of $g(A)$ as $x$. Then find the least positive integer $k$ such that $(A-\lambda I)^kx=0$, which makes $v=(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}x\ne0$ an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: What about multiplicity?  If $\lambda_{k} = \lambda_{k+1}$ won't this algorithm give me the same eigenvector for $k$ and $k+1$?

Comment: @JimNewton It only gives you one eigenvector.

Comment: OK, great, so this leads me back to the original question/confusion.  The wikipedia article (in the 3x3 Matrix section) shows (vaguely and unsatisfactorily) how to extract the eigenvectors from various products of $(A-\lambda_i I)$.   I don't understand how to generalize this (to write a program to do it).  The wikipedia article takes one vector $(-4,-4,4)$ from $(A-I)^2$, then a 2nd vector $(4,2,-1)$ from $(A-I)(A+I)$, and finally takes a 3rd vector from $A+I$ claiming that either $(2,3,-1)$ or $(6,5,-3)$ will work because they are *generalized* eigenvectors.

Comment: @JimNewton The generalised eigenspace for $\lambda$ is the column space of $g(A)$. There is an algorithm to obtain the generalised eigenvectors for transforming $A$ into a Jordan form (using recursive column reductions from $(A-\lambda I)^{m-1}g(A),\,(A-\lambda I)^{m-2}g(A),\ldots$ down to $g(A)$), but I don’t want to include it here because the answer will become too long. A related but different approach can be found in this [handout](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/courses/jcf.pdf).

Comment: I took a look at the handout.  There are a few questions I'd love to clarify.  What is the best forum to do that?

Comment: @JimNewton Sorry, I don’t know. MSE is the only mathematics forum(?) that I’ve joined.